# How to make IBM Informix 12.10 listen to IPv4

Tags: database, informix, ipv6, ipv4

I have installed IBM Informix 12.10 in Windows 7 64-bit OS. The issue is Informix is binding to IPv6 by default: refer to this Tech Note on [Configuring Informix on a host containing both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639070).

I want to make Informix listen to IPv4 and I found the above link, but I am bit confused on what is the exact steps to configure it. Any thoughts? For example where / how can I configure DBSERVERALIASES as per the above link.

Comment: Your Windows machine can be in one of three states:  (1) it has an IPv6 address only, or (2) it has an IPv4 address only, or (3) it has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  In each case, multiple addresses marginally complicates things, but doesn't alter the basic conclusion.  If you have (1), then there isn't an IPv4 address to listen on.  If you have (2), there isn't an issue; it can only listen on IPv4 addresses.  It's only if you have (3) that there is any issue.  DBSERVERALIASES is specified in the `$ONCONFIG` configuration file, supported by the `sqlhosts` file and the system networking.

Comment: Please clarify which state applies to your machine, and go with the inevitable if it is in state (1) or (2).  If it is in state (3), then does your machine have multiple names, one for each IP address?